# How to add kernel module to LTIB target image

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, kernel-module

I have create a new Kernel Module following [The Linux Kernel Module Programming Guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/lkmpg.pdf).I want to add my module to the [config -> Package selection -> package List]
and distribute my module with target image

►Development Environment

- boundary device sabrelite board
- [LTIB (i.MX6 kernel 4.1.0)](http://boundarydevices.com/mx6-kernel-4-1-0/)

I put my kernel module's source on [/home/USER/ltib/rpm/BUILD/myModule] path. (just like hello_mod example module which explained in "*The Linux Kernel Module Programming Guide*")
but when i build target image it does not compile.

hello_mod example module can be selected in configuration mode(./ltib -m config).
How can I add my module to this config -> Package selection -> package List

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to build from make menuconfig, that you probably should change the makefiles.

Check this [documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kbuild/makefiles.txt) from the linux kernel. Taken from it:

> *Normal developers* are people who work on features such as device drivers, file systems, and network protocols.  These people need to
>   maintain the kbuild Makefiles for the subsystem they are working on. 
>   In order to do this effectively, they need some overall knowledge
>   about the kernel Makefiles, plus detailed knowledge about the public
>   interface for kbuild.